# How can anything possibly bind to this forward function?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I think I'm getting awfully close to understanding this. It seems that there are two overloads for the `forward` function, and I thought two overloads are needed to make it work, but as far as I can see one of them is completely useless, and it works with just one:

```
template <typename T>
T&& forward(T&& arg)
{// Never gets called.
    // I can't see how since every argument from another function is always
    // an lvalue, nothing can bind to it
    return static_cast<T&&>(arg); 
}

template <typename T>
T&& forward(T& arg)
{// Just this one seems to do the job
    return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}

template <typename Type>
void emplace(Type&& arg)
{
    forward<Type>(arg);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int& intref = a;
    
    emplace(a);
    emplace(int());
}
```

Both call the one `forward` function, the other one can go, right?

Comment: Is there a reason you are defining your own `forward()` functions instead of using [`std::forward()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward)?

Comment: In emplace T&& => rvalue but when you're passing it into forward it will switch into T&. So you can use forward(static_cast<T&&>(arg));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For illustration, you can change the code to this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T&& forward(T&& arg)
{   
    // gets called when the parameter is a rvalue reference
    std::cout << "called\n";
    return static_cast<T&&>(arg); 
}

template <typename T>
T&& forward(T& arg)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}

template <typename Type>
void emplace(Type&& arg)
{
    forward<Type>(forward<Type>(arg));
}

int main()
{
    emplace(int());
}
```

To get [output](https://godbolt.org/z/WrMc1osvM):

```
called
```

In `emplace` the call `forward<Type>(arg);` does not call `T&& forward(T&& arg)` because `arg` in `emplace` is not a rvalue reference, sloppy speaking, because it has a name. You can call `void emplace(Type&& arg)` with an rvalue, but the argument `arg` isn't one. Actually thats the reason `std::forward` is needed in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

The 1st overload is used for forwarding rvalues (as rvalues). E.g.

```
forward<int>(0);
```

In `emplace` you're forwarding `arg` which is lvalue as named variable.